# nested dropzones in fine-uploader uploads file twice

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, fine-uploader

I have a requirement where we need an extra dropzone (on a table row) but the container div also needs to be a dropzone. Is there any way to stop fineuploader uploading the file twice if I drop a file into a table row?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think we've come across a nested drop zone requirement yet.  So, in its current state, this will not work.  This is due to the fact that the drop event bubbles from your inner drop zone up to your parent drop zone.  Fine Uploader does not stop the drop event from bubbling.  Perhaps it should though.  I'll have to investigate the consequences of preventing propagation of the drop event before this is addressed in the code.

Please [open up a feature request in the Github project's issue tracker](https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader/issues/new) so we can discuss further.  In the meantime, you can attempt to work around this by changing the following code at the end of the drag & drop module ([dnd.js](https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader/blob/1df1a15e38c526416b4d8214b8a92a2a6aecb40a/client/js/dnd.js)) from:

```
disposeSupport.attach(element, 'drop', function(e){
    if (!isOrSetDropDisabled()) {
        if (!isValidFileDrag(e)) {
            return;
        }

        e.preventDefault();
        options.onDrop(e);
    }
});
```

...to:

```
disposeSupport.attach(element, 'drop', function(e){
    if (!isOrSetDropDisabled()) {
        if (!isValidFileDrag(e)) {
            return;
        }

        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        options.onDrop(e);
    }
});
```

I haven't tested the above theory, but it seems like this would solve your issue.  I can take a closer look tomorrow.

Comment: Ok thanks. I might test it myself and open up a PR if it's ok

Comment: Sure thing.  If you do, please do so against the develop branch.